# Detect clusters from graph

Tags: python, matplotlib, machine-learning, feature-detection

Sorry for my English but I will try to explain my problem statement.I have a csv with near about 156 columns. I want to plot the Scatter graph with one of the columns as X axis and another one as Y axis. By making combinations of 150 columns i will be generating 11K graphs.Now i have to go through each graph to see is there distinguishable clusters in graph.but to go with visual route it will take whole lot of time.and in feature if graph changes i have to repeat the work. So i am looking for solution where i can detect which graph has clusters.

I will provide one of the sample graph generated by using python matplot library.[Image link here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6hoPj.png)

I will also sharing some of the column structure which i am having.

col1           col2           col3           col4           col5

0.05414   0.0027070  0.012994    0.0508931   0.042772063
0.00155    0.0001942      0.000388   0.0120453  0.0069943

I am intermediate at Python-2.7